# How to properly pass HTTP error code to error handling middleware?

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, express

I'm building RESTful API with node.js and express framework and I'm looking for a way to build single error handling middleware. My current approach is:

```
router.get('/some-resource', (req, res, next) => {
  // some logic that resolves to BAD REQUEST
  const error = new Error('Bad request example message')
  error.code = 400; // should I do this?
  next(error);
});
```

My error handling middleware is the following:

```
const env = process.env.NODE_ENV;
const ErrorHandler = (error, req, res, next) => {
  const {code, stack} = error;
  if (env === 'production')
    return res.sendStatus(code || 500);
  res.status(code).send(stack);
};

module.exports = ErrorHandler;
```

Should I just assign HTTP error codes to the **Error** object's instance or is it considered a bad pracice? Should response code be specified at the route level? Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Passing the code with a regular Error object is perfectly fine, but `code` is a bit too generic and might also be used by other Errors so `httpCode` might be better.

But I personally would prefer to use custom classes so that I don't need to remember the error codes or accidentally mistype the numbers and you can clearly identify that it is really an error that represents a http error code, and that `code` does not refere to something else.

So a setup could look like this:

```
 class HttpError extends Error {
    constructor(code, message) {
      super(message)
      this.code = code
    }
 }


 class BadRequestError extends HttpError {
    constructor(message) {
      super(400, message)
    }
 }
```

And the error handling middleware could look like that:

```js
const env = process.env.NODE_ENV;
const ErrorHandler = (error, req, res, next) => {
  if( error instanceof HttpError ) {
    res.status(error.code || 500)
  } else {
    // maybe some additional internal logging that a "wrong" error object arrived here
    res.status(500)
  }

  if (env === 'production') {
    res.send();
  } else {
    res.send(error.stack);
  }
};

module.exports = ErrorHandler;
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct way of doing this, is to set a `cause` in the error's optional options prop.

```
const error = new Error("Message here", {
  cause: res.status,
});
```

Then in the error handling, you have `error.cause` available.

This will help if you're using Typescript, as `error.code` isn't a property on the Error type, but options { cause } is.

Answer (score -1):

You're on the right track. The MDN documentation for the [Error object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error) will help. Also, the cross platform [StackTrace.js](https://www.stacktracejs.com/) can be really helpful in your scenario.